# Update objects in an array inside map Function React or React-Hooks or React-Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

it is deleting all objects except last one from the array instead of updating a property of all objects, want to update 'ItemDeliveryStatus' of all objects inside map function

```
const [arrayList, setArrayList] = useState([
        { Id: 1, Name:'A', ItemDeliveryStatus:1 },
        { Id: 2, Name:'B', ItemDeliveryStatus:1 },
        { Id: 3, Name:'C', ItemDeliveryStatus:1 },
        { Id: 4, Name:'D', ItemDeliveryStatus:1 },
      ])

const [returnCount, setReturnCount ]=useState(0)

const updateAllObjects=()=>
{
  arrayList.map(items=>
        {

            if(items.ItemDeliveryStatus==1)
            {
                setArrayList([{ ...items, ItemDeliveryStatus:4}])
            }

            if (items.ItemDeliveryStatus==4)
            {
               setReturnCount(prev=>prev+1)                        
            }
        })
}

final Result Should be like this 
([
        { Id: 1, Name:'A', ItemDeliveryStatus:4 },
        { Id: 2, Name:'B', ItemDeliveryStatus:4 },
        { Id: 3, Name:'C', ItemDeliveryStatus:4 },
        { Id: 4, Name:'D', ItemDeliveryStatus:4 },
  ])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can update like this for all object:

```
const updateAllObjects = (value) => {
  setArrayList(
    arrayList.map((item) => {
      if (item.ItemDeliveryStatus == 1) {
        return { ...item, ItemDeliveryStatus: value };
      };
      return item;
    })
  );
};
```